# How can you nest curly-braced model delimiters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where the user can select a database table name from a dropdown, the app makes an http call out to the database, retrieves the table column names as well as data from those columns, and returns this data to the script.  So far, so good.  My code is set up to handle the fact that I do not know anything about the table - the column names, nor how many columns the table has.  I dump this data into an object called tableData, where tableData.columns contains all of the column names and tableData.results contains the data contained in the rows for those columns in the database.  This object may look like this:

```
{ "columns": [{ "name": "lo_code"}, 
              { "name": "lo_desc"},
              { "name": "lo_inactive"}],
  "results": [{ "lo_code": "7" , "lo_desc": "Staff Area 7" , "lo_inactive": "0"},
              { "lo_code": "12", "lo_desc": "Staff Area 12", "lo_inactive": "0"},
              { "lo_code": "15", "lo_desc": "Staff Area 15", "lo_inactive": "1"},
              { "lo_code": "M" , "lo_desc": "Miscellaneous", "lo_inactive": "0"}]}
```

What I want to do is create a table with the columns in the header row and then all of the remaining data in the rows below.  I have the following to create the table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in tableData.columns">{{column.name}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in tableData.results">
            <td ng-repeat="column in tableData.columns"> ??????? </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm not sure how reference the object data in the td.  I tried

```
<td ng-repeat="column in tableData.columns">{{result.{{column.name}}}}</td>
```

but that gives me an unexpected token error.  I'm guessing that my nesting of angular model delimiters isn't the way to go about this.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_de_dee/gNnRB/2/) with sample object data.  So, what can I put in place of ??????? to get the data that I want?

Comment: what about `{{result[column.name]}}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td ng-repeat="column in tableData.columns">{{ result[column.name] }}</td>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UT8E2/

Comment: YES!!!  It didn't occur to me that once I used the brackets, I was effectively in the angular environment for the long haul, and I was trying to reference each object value independently.  Now I see that once I've crossed into the model (for result), I can then reference column directly.  Thank you!!